# WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 - SCIM2 REST - Get all required attributes?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm calling SCIM2 REST service to get user information based on ID but it doesn't return all user data.when I call `https://localhost:9444/scim2/Users/8f9d1e34-c340-4ebe-af11-fa0c4575f676` passing username and password (BASIC) I get this payload:

```
{
  "emails": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "value": "test@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "created": "2020-10-09T11:29:42.809803400Z",
    "location": "https://localhost:9444/scim2/Users/8f9d1e34-c340-4ebe-af11-fa0c4575f676",
    "lastModified": "2020-10-09T11:29:42.809803400Z",
    "resourceType": "User"
  },
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "value": "Internal/everyone"
    }
  ],
  "id": "8f9d1e34-c340-4ebe-af11-fa0c4575f676",
  "userName": "test"
}
```

But this user has more attributes as seem below:

[image]

How do I return whole user data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCIM GET request on `/Users/{user-id}` endpoint will return the SCIM user attributes which defined under `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User` and `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User` claim dialects (mgt console -> Main Menu-> Identity tab -> Claims -> List). If the particular attribute (i.e local claim) is not mapped to a SCIM user attribute that value won't be returned in the SCIM user GET response.
In order to map such local attributes to SCIM attributes, you can follow the instructions in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api.

Moreover,
You can find SCIM core user attribute definitions [here](https://github.com/wso2/charon/blob/f5229c1ed55548d74b833e1a04656ac695899d9b/modules/charon-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/charon3/core/schema/SCIMSchemaDefinitions.java). If an attribute's returned characteristic is

1. Returned.ALWAYS  -> Always returned in the response
2. Returned.DEFAULT -> Return in the response only if that attribute has a value
3. Returned.NEVER -> Never return in the response

Comment: Hello! Thank you (again) for your answer! In general, I understood the mechanics but one question still remains: There is an attribute called "fullName" under 
http://wso2.org/claims. If my understanding is correct, only way to return additional attribute, even if it is available and marked as "Supported by Default" and "Required" is to set it in "scim2-schema-extension.config"? What if I'd like to set it when creating new user? Just send it in JSON payload?

Comment: Please note this attribute already existis under claim configuration, how do I return it by default in SCIM2/REST/User API call?

Comment: In SCIM formattedName is used as the full name(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7643#section-8.2). So, in WSO2 server you can use http://wso2.org/claims/formattedName claim to store fullname.
If you want to return http://wso2.org/claims/fullname in the response, you have to add it to the extensions because fullname local claim hasn't been mapped to any scim claim in urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User or urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User by default.

Comment: eg: 1. use 'fullname' for every places that 'customClaim' is used in 
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api
2. Skip "Add the custom claim" section (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#add-the-custom-claim)
3. Map urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:fullname external uri to http://wso2.org/claims/fullname local claim in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#map-the-custom-claim section

Comment: when creating the user, it should be added into the request body as:

 "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User": {
        "fullname": "test user"
  }

Comment: Great! What if I'd like to keep as standard as possible? How do I ADD/UPDATE field  wso2.org/claims/formattedName through SCIM2/REST? PS: I'll try your sugestion anyway because it solves the question anyway. Thanks!

Comment: This is the format of name object in SCIM (Refer: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7643#section-8.2)  "name": {
    "givenName": "Kim",
    "familyName": "Berry",
    "formatted": "Kim Berry"
  }

Comment: Yes, you're right if I pass just "name": {"formatted":"name"} actually works when creating new user. I need to enable it in claims to see it in admin console. OK, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you one more time!

Comment: Hey, one more thing... Why postalCode is not working? For instance, name works according to IETF schema, tryied the same for addresses[].postalCode but it doesn't work. Is there any additional detail am I missing? In case of name, I didnt do any configuration, just sent in JSON to SCIM2 REST and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222985/discussion-between-anuradha-karunarathna-and-emilio-numazaki).